# Generating tracking numbers for orders

Tags: java

I have this class which will be used from my main class and will be creating objects of class `Sale`:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Sale {
int size = 0; 
public int scode = 0 ; // sell code 
public String cname ; // client name 
public int cphone ; // client phone 
public String sdate ; // selling date 
public int cost ; // final cost 
public int aItems[] // sold product

public Sale (Item aItems[],String cname, String cphone, String sdate) {
     this.aItems = aItems ; 
     this.cname= cname;
     this.sphone= sphone;
     this.sdate= sdate;
     }

     public void setsItems(Items aItems) {
     this.aItems= aItems;
     }

     public void setCname (String name) {
     this.name= name;
     }

     public void setCphone(String cphone) {
     this.cphone= cphone;
     }

        public void setSDate(String sdate) {
            this.sdate= sdate;
         }
```

The project says that in my main class I must have a way to review any sale made by entering the unique id number of the sale which will be created in this class. My problem is that I don't know how to set my class so that every time it's called from my main it will generate a new id number, starting from 1 and increasing by 1 every time. 
Any ideas?

Comment: -1 Homework question. But in the real world you would probably use a database autoincrement field or something external to your application to track the ID numbers you've already given out.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `static` member variable to store the ID number of the last sale.  A static member is a variable that is part of the class, not the object.  This value can get incremented like you want.

Make a new method to access that variable that also increments the variable by one each time you generate a new ID.

In your main, call the Sale.generateNewID() method, then pass that new ID into the constructor of your Sale class.

```
public class Sale {

     public static int idCount = 0;

     public static int generateNewID() {
        return ++idCount;
     }

     // this is a new member variable to store the id of the sale
     private int id; 

     // note: added id parameter to constructor
     public Sale (int theId, Item aItems[],String cname, String cphone, String sdate) {
        this.id = theId;
        // other constructor assignments that you had go here.
     }

     ... // rest of your code

}
```

Comment: please help me a bit more here. I am kind of newbie in java so i will have to ask you to explain a bit better. Thanks